# Live call transfer by using asterisk

Tags: linux, asterisk, centos7, pbx, freepbx

i want to transfer a call from first executive to second executive when customer call to first executive by mistake? How first executive can map customer to second executive by pressing a key by using asterisk technology?

Answer (score 1):

Default transfer is *2. For exact code check features.conf

You also have dialplan Transfer application you can map on any other extension.

You have Transfer ami command usable via asterisk managment interface(AMI)

Comment: [from-pstn]

exten => _X.,1,NoOp(----------Live call Transfer------------)
same => n,Answer()
same => n,set(__KEY=0)
same => n,set(__TONEPATH=/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/indo1)
same => n,Read(KEY,${TONEPATH},2, ,2,5)
same => n,GotoIf($[${KEY}=1]?Y:N)
same => n(Y),Dial(dahdi/g1/9729987008,30,T))
same => n(N),Hangup()

[DIRECTANSWERED]
exten => 102,1,noop(CALL_ANSWERED ==============${UNIQUE_ID}==================)
same => n,set(__ANSWER=${CDR(answer)})
same => 102,Dial(dahdi/g1/8800379946,30)

Comment: This is my code of extensions.conf file in this code i want that when a customer call firstly he contact with executive first(i.e. 9729987008) and how executive can map customer to another exective by pressing some which is on 102 extension?

Comment: changes in features.conf file                                                            [featuremap]
blindxfer = #1
atxfer = *2

Comment: after that i am not able to transfer a call

Comment: Thank You so much sir for help,Finally its working now

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague, but since you put freepbx on the tags, I suppose you are using freepbx generated dialplan.

If I understand well, when a certain inbound context calls *executive1* you want
1) them to be automagically redirected on *executive2* before *executive1* answers
or
2) *executive1* answers, realizes that call is wrong and blind-transfers call to *executive2* pressing a single button (= DTMF).

## CASE 1 - Automatic redirection

Edit your /etc/asterisk/extension_custom.conf

```
[your inbound context]
exten => <executive 1 number>,Goto(your inbound context, executive2 number, 1)
```

You can find the name of your inbound context in the freepbx automatic generated dialplan, or in the freepbx GUI

## CASE2 - In call transfer

Refer to this [post](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Custom+Dynamic+Features) to define a new feature code for in-call transfer. Unfortunately your feature code will be likely some #digit
Associate the application

```
Goto(your inbound context, executive2 number, 1)
```

to the feature code

Hope this will help.